# Magento2 Image not saving into custom db table

Tags: database, image

Created a form fields are saving data into db table but image data is not getting saved.
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue(); Tried to print but it dose not showing image data.

My controller file.

```
class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
 * @var GridFactory
 */
var $gridFactory;

protected $fileSystem;

protected $uploaderFactory;

protected $adapterFactory;

/**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param GridFactory $gridFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    GridFactory $gridFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->gridFactory = $gridFactory;
    $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
    $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
    $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    //echo '<pre/>'; print_r($data); die('a');

    /* for delete image */

    if (isset($data['img']['delete'])) {
        if ($data['img']['delete'] == 1) {
            $data['img'] = '';
        }
    }

    /* for upload image */
    if ((isset($_FILES['img']['name'])) && ($_FILES['img']['name'] != '') && (!isset($data['img']['delete']))) {
        //echo '<pre/>'; print_r($_FILES);die('ss');
        try
        {
            $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'img']);
            $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
            $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
            $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('custom/imageviewer/images');

            //echo "<br/>destination path".$destinationPath;

            $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);

            //print_r($result); die('result');

            if (!$result) {
                throw new LocalizedException
                (
                    __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                );

            }

            $imagePath = 'custom/imageviewer/images' . $result['file'];

            //echo "<br/> Image store ".$imagePath;

            $data['img'] = $imagePath;

        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__("Image not Upload Pleae Try Again"));
        }

    }
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);die('a');


    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    //print_r($data);die('ss');
    if (!$data) {
        $this->_redirect('grid/grid/addrow');
        return;
    }
    try {
        $rowData = $this->gridFactory->create();
        $rowData->setData($data);
        if (isset($data['id'])) {
            $rowData->setEntityId($data['id']);
        }
        //die('stop');
        $rowData->save();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Image For 360 view been successfully saved.'));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
    }
    $this->_redirect('grid/grid/index');
}
```